# Why can't return be expressed in one line when using a Switch Expression?

Tags: java, return, expression, java-14, switch-expression

```java
while (true) {
    console.mainMenu();
    String inputCommand = console.input();
    switch(inputCommand) {
        case "exit" -> return;
        case "create" -> {
            Voucher voucher = createVoucher();
            voucherRepository.save(voucher);
        }
        case "list" -> voucherRepository.findByIdAll();
        default -> console.output(Error.INVALID_COMMAND);
    }
}
```

An error occurs in `case "exit" -> return;` in the above code.

In a switch expression, if the code is expressed as a single line, you can omit the brackets, but it continues to ask for the addition of the brackets.

This is the **compilation error** I'm getting:

```
error: unexpected statement in case, expected is an expression, 
a block or a throw statement case "exit" -> return;
```

Why is the problem happening?

If I add a bracket, it works well.

But I wonder why the error occurs when the brackets are removed?

Comment: 1) that is not a `switch expression`, just a `switch statement` - according [JLS 14.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) (and compiler); 2) the error message should give information... like "*invalid expression as statement*" (try using `{ }` around the `return;`)

Comment: and `return;` is not an expression, it is not a block and neither a throw statement - as already suggested, use `{ }` around it, to make it a block

Comment: I reproduced the problem here: https://jdoodle.com/ia/ppq.  It will compile if the `return;` statement is surrounded by `{` and `}`.  The question is why?

Comment: @user16320675 The goal was to reproduce the OPs error message, obviously not that Java is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a **statement** as a rule (the part after the arrow `->`) in a [**switch expression**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). It must be either an expression or block (which can contain a statement or multiple statements)

These are valid **rules** according to the specification:

> ***SwitchRule:***
>
> - SwitchLabel -> **Expression** ;
> - SwitchLabel -> **Block**
> - SwitchLabel -> **ThrowStatement**

Example of valid rules:

```
int a = 9;
switch(a) {
    case 1 -> System.out.println(a);                 // Expression
    case 2 -> {return;}                              // Block
    default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // ThrowStatement
}
```

These are the definitions of expression, statement and block from the [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html).

**Expression**

> An expression is a **construct** made up of **variables**, **operators**, and **method invocations**, which are constructed according to the syntax of the language, that evaluates to a single value.

**Statement**

> Statements are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A statement forms a **complete unit of execution**. The following types of expressions can be made into a statement by terminating the expression with a semicolon (;).

**Block**

> A block is a **group** of zero or more **statements** between balanced braces

`return;` is a not a variable or method invocation, it's a *statement*. Hence, it must be enclosed in curly bases to form a block of code.